# How to insert posts from a category into WordPress theme page?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have got into a problem while making a custom theme in WordPress. I have written an index.php on which I am trying to bring posts from a category named news and events.

I have been using get_posts and I am getting the title name and also the content but when it comes to the permalink I am getting the right link on he page but it is not getting me on the posts page. It is getting me on the index page itself. The link on the top page is also getting the same as the permalink.

Comment: Please post the code that performs this action. Without it we can't see what might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you should create a "single.php" file for post view page if wordpress not found "single.php" file to your theme then it called "index.php" file so for that you are redirect to home page. now please checked the wordpress theme hierarchy.

The single post template file is used to render a single post. WordPress uses the following path:

- single-{post-type}.php – First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post type. For example, post type is product, WordPress would look for single-product.php.
- single.php – WordPress then falls back to single.php.
- singular.php – Then it falls back to singular.php.
- index.php – Finally, as mentioned above, WordPress ultimately falls back to index.php.

Comment: thnk you very very much friend
this has worked for me 
but i want to tell you that now my post page has begun but now i am not getting my all posts using the get_posts. I am only getting the last post which i have inserted in the last.
Coul you please help me with that please.

Comment: can you update you code with `get_posts` function argument. so i can easily get problem thanks